# Python, regular expression search matchobj triggers error

Tags: python, regex, search, regex-group

I somehow know that the answer to this question will be obvious, but I've spent several days trying unsuccessfully to find out why I don't seem to be able to find the reg.exp. mach object in the script below.
Here's the error messsage I get:

```
    subject:     Re: Why DOJ BMFEA Baton Rouge rejected Gonzalaz Pen Code 99999 death case


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\test_search4Sender_aaB.py", line 46, in <module>
    print fn_cull_sender_info(date_string_raw)
  File "C:\Apps\UtilitiesByMarc\test_search4Sender_aaB.py", line 35, in fn_cull_sender_info
    print 'Line 35:  matchObj found\n str(match_obj.group(0)) = ' +  str(match_obj.group(0))
NameError: global name 'match_obj' is not defined
```

The following is the code:

```
import sys
import re, pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

def fn_get_srctxt_hg_datestring_rawdata_from_clipbd(): 
    this_scriptz_FULLName = sys.argv[0]
    try:
        date_string_raw = sys.argv[1]
        return returnval    
    except:
        date_string_raw = ''

        import win32clipboard

        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        clip_text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()    

        date_string_raw = clip_text
        returnval = clip_text
        return returnval    




def fn_cull_sender_info(date_string_raw): # 
    # Do re replacements
    import re
    sender_info = 'Line 29 empty'
    print '\n\nLine 30:  date_string_raw = [starts on next line...]\n' + str(date_string_raw) + '\n' + 'x'*80 + '\n'
    srchpatrn = r"(from:\t )(([A-Za-z\. ]+?)(?: ))?([A-Za-z.\-_0-9]+@[A-Za-z.\-_0-9].+?\.(?:com|org|net))"        

    matchObj = re.search(srchpatrn, date_string_raw)
    if matchObj:
        print 'Line 35:  matchObj found\n str(match_obj.group(0)) = ' +  str(match_obj.group(0))
        sender_info = str(match_obj.group(0))
    return sender_info


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    harvey = fn_get_srctxt_hg_datestring_rawdata_from_clipbd()
    print harvey
    date_string_raw = harvey
    print '*****'*50
    print '\n\n'
    print fn_cull_sender_info(date_string_raw)
```

And the following (which is text produced by another function [not shown here]) is the text that I have in the Windows Clipboard when I run the python code above:

```
sender_display_name = matchObj.search(date_string_raw).group(2)#.strip() 
sender_eml =      matchObj.search(date_string_raw).group(4)
```

I've spent days trying to find out what I'm doing wrong.
I want to capture regular expression groups 3 and 4 into string variables, e.g.

But since I can't get the matchObj to return as True, I can't get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've previously defined `matchObj`, not `match_obj`.

Comment: This kind of problems are easily detected with a syntax checking tool like [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes).

Comment: I use pylint, very straightforward.